# Api lvl 23 problems with MaterialButton

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, layout

The problem just is thrown at Samsung devices, j7 and j2

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp/com.myapp.activity.LoginActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #46: Binary XML file line #46: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
```

This is my buttons code

```
   <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Button"
        android:id="@+id/btn_google_signin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="Sign-in"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:cornerRadius="10dp"
        app:icon="@drawable/googlelogo"
        app:iconSize="30dp"
        app:iconTint="@null"/>
```

Styles

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    ...
    </>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem occurs only on those two devices, open an issue on the material components page to report the problem. The class you refer to via XML is correct. Samsung may have damaged something within their framework, I personally had several problems (not related to MaterialButton) on OnePlus devices.

In addition, I personally use MaterialButton on several projects, which have a strong samsung userbase and I have not received any type of crash related to the buttons.

Just out of curiosity, besides saying "error inflating class MaterialButton" you are not told anything else? Generally this type of errors includes something extra in the logcat

[Material Components for Android GitHub page link](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android)